# SAP UI5 : Unable to bind a controller variable in xml

Tags: sapui5

Button on click of which the variable is getting changed:

```
<f:content> 
    <Button icon="sap-icon://edit" press="editClick" type="Transparent"></Button>
</f:content>
```

xml code where i need 2-way binding:

```
<VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
       <form:SimpleForm id="SimpleFormDisplayColumn_oneGroup">
           <form:content>
               <Label text="{i18n>contextofusage}"/> 
               <Text text="{contextofusagetext}" visible="{!isInfoEditable}"/>
               <Input type="Text" visible="{isInfoEditable}" value="{contextofusagetext}"></Input>
           </form:content>
       </form:SimpleForm>
   </VBox>
```

controller:

```
var isInfoEditable=false;
   return Controller.extend("abc.controller.Detail", {
      editInfoClick: function(event){
            if(isInfoEditable){
               isInfoEditable=false;
            }
            else{
                isInfoEditable=true;
            }

        }
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have tried nothing, but I will try to guide you:

You cannot simply declare a variable in your controller and then use it in your view. That's not how UI5 works. Instead create a model and bind it to your view. I also give my models a name, in this case `"view"`:

```
onInit: function() {
    var oViewModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
        isInfoEditable: false
    });
    this.getView().setModel(oViewModel, "view");
}
```

Then use it in your view. Make sure that you use the name of your model (`"view"`) in your bindings. If you want to do more than simply use the raw value (e.g. negate it) you have to use [expression binding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0.html). Also you have to use an absolute path starting with `/`:

```
<form:SimpleForm id="SimpleFormDisplayColumn_oneGroup">
    <form:content>
        <Label text="{i18n>contextofusage}"/> 
        <Text text="{contextofusagetext}" visible="{= !${view>/isInfoEditable} }"/>
        <Input type="Text" visible="{view>/isInfoEditable}" value="{contextofusagetext}"></Input>
    </form:content>
</form:SimpleForm>
```

When you click on the button you have to modify/toggle the value in your model:

```
editClick: function (oEvent) {
    var oViewModel = this.getView().getModel("view");
    var bIsEditable = oViewModel.getProperty("/isInfoEditable");
    // negate the current value and set it as the new value
    oViewModel.setProperty("/isInfoEditable", !bIsEditable);
}
```

I suggest strongly reading on the basics of UI5. Your approach looks more like Vue.js, but UI5 has its own paradigms.

Comment: Thank you Marc. I have recently started learning UI5. Since I have worked on Angular I assumed that data binding may work the same way in UI5 too. But I was wrong.